# Laravel session gets suddenly destroyed

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I have a multi-page form that handles sport event registrations. We are getting a lot of users (about 15% of all users, platform/browser independent) that experience the following error:

The form contains the following pages:

1. Start
2. Details
3. Team
4. Class
5. Batch
6. Merchandise
7. Survey
8. Complete

On every page, we check if the session contains the data from the previous page. If not, we redirect him back.

The issue that encounters is that the 15% group gets redirected back after inputting data on step 4.

This probably means that the session/data gets corrupted in the store function from step 4, but I don't have any clue how/why/where. But if this is the issue, it doesn't make sense that only 15% of our users get the issue. Also, after hours of trying, we where not able to reproduce this error.

I know the session gets completely flushed/destroyed because the users get cascaded back: showBatchPage reverts the user back to showClassPage, showClassPage to showMembersPage, showMembersPage to showStartPage etc. We also log these reverts.

My code looks like the following:

```
<?php

public function saveClassPage($slug)
{
    $rules = [];
    $messages = [];
    $memberClasses = [];    

    // prepare solo error messages    
    foreach (Session::get('entry.members') as $id => $member)
    {
        if (!isset($member['group'])) {
            $rules["class.{$id}"] = 'required';
            $messages["class.{$id}.required"] = "Please select a class for member {$member['firstname']} {$member['lastname']}";
        }
    }

    // prepare team error messages
    foreach (Session::get('entry.groups', []) as $id => $group)
    {
        $rules["group.{$id}"] = 'required';
        $messages["group.{$id}.required"] = "Please select a class for group {$group['name']}";
    }

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

    // loop trough solo members and set class
    foreach (Input::get('class', []) as $i => $class)
    {
        Session::put("entry.members.{$i}.class", $class);

        // if there is only one class in the batch, assign it
        $memberClasses[$i] = ClassModel::find($class);
        if ($memberClasses[$i]->batches()->count() < 2) {
            Session::put("entry.members.{$i}.batch", $memberClasses[$i]->batches()->first()->id);
        }
    }

    // loop trough teams and set class
    foreach (Input::get('group', []) as $i => $class)
    {
        foreach (Session::get("entry.groups.{$i}.members", []) as $id)
        {
            Session::put("entry.members.{$id}.class", $class);

            // if there is only one class in the batch, assign it
            $memberClasses[$id] = ClassModel::find($class);
            if ($memberClasses[$id]->batches()->count() < 2) {
                Session::put("entry.members.{$i}.batch", $memberClasses[$id]->batches()->first()->id);
            }
        }
        Session::put("entry.groups.{$i}.class", $class);
    }

    $allClassesAreEmpty = true;
    foreach ($memberClasses as $class)
    {
        if ($class->batches()->count() > 1) {
            $allClassesAreEmpty = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        // skip batch page if there is only one batch
        if ($allClassesAreEmpty) {
            return Redirect::action('EventEntryController@showExtrasPage', array('slug' => $slug));
        } else {
            return Redirect::action('EventEntryController@showBatchPage', array('slug' => $slug));
        }
    }

    return Redirect::action('EventEntryController@showClassPage', array('slug' => $slug))->withErrors($validator);
}

public function showBatchPage($slug)
{
    $firstMember = head( Session::get('entry.members', []) );

    if (!isset($firstMember['class'])) {
        Log::info('showBatchPage@revertToClass');

        return Redirect::action('EventEntryController@showClassPage', array('slug' => $slug));
    }

    // other stuff (preparing view data etc.)

    return View::make('entry/batch', $viewData);
}
```

My app/config/session.php

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'file',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => array(2, 100),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

);
```

Comment: Can you please post all of your app/config/session.php code?

Comment: Have you tried switching session types? Perhaps Database, or install memcache?

Comment: No, not yet. How do you think will this matter? Since the issue happens at the same position, and not always (if I completely replicate a affected users actions, I got no problems at all), to me it doesn't like to be an issue with the session provider.

Comment: Its about ruling things out. If the issue occurs in a DB session - then you know its not your file session. But at the moment you dont know that for sure - and its probably the simplest option to change.

Comment: Oh - one more thing - change your cookie to something without an underscore - some older IE browsers dont like cookies with underscores.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Changed the sessions to database and the cookie name, so lets see what happens now.

Comment: Nope, stil the same issue after changing to DB sessions.

Comment: Are you using Sentry to manage users?

Comment: No, the default Laravel user model. The users who experience the error are in the public area of the site, so not logged in at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on a local box (Dev), to avoid messing up with other Laravel apps using the same default `Session Cookie Name` and the same `domain`:

1. Clear all `browser cookies` related to the domain used by your Laravel app to troubleshoot.
2. Change your `Session Cookie Name` to a more unique one (without underscore if need be).

I you use the default session driver `file`, make sure you have write permissions for the folder `app/storage`.

Comment: Tried this already, but didn't work. Changed cookie name to a unique one, and later to db driver to exclude file system errors. Still not found the problem, and still not able to reproduce it.